# Not sure why this selector returns size 0

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to write some javascript to ensure that a table has *lineNumber* tr elements of a specific class inside it.  I have the following loop to do so:

```
 while ($(".functionCodeLine").size() < lineNumber) {

        console.log($(".functionCodeLine").size());

        funcLineRow = $('<tr class="functionCodeLine"></tr>');
        table.append(funcLineRow);

...
}
```

But in my log statement I see that the returned size is always 0.  If I inspect the DOM I see that new tr's are being added with the class attribute.  So I'm at a little of a loss to understand why size is always 0 and the loop never terminates.  What am I missing?

[Here's a jsfiddle.net demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ZdmmD/).

Comment: Please create a http://jsfiddle.net/ demo.

Comment: Why are you using a such loop ? You just have to: get the actual number of elements, get the desired number of elements, make the difference of both then use a `for(i=0;i=diffenrence)` loop

Comment: @pomeh Assuming the OP can get it to work, a `while` loop is more succinct than a `for` loop in this instance.

Comment: Try `funcLineRow = '<tr class="functionCodeLine"></tr>';` - any change? The concept itself [is working](http://jsfiddle.net/2j7pY/).

Comment: @pomeh, You are using a loop too. What a surprise.

Comment: BUT the while loop will be slower since it keeps have to read the DOM over and over again.

Comment: Has the table variable been appended to the DOM or does it directly reference a DOM element in this example?  If not, that would explain why you can find it using table.find(...) but not by querying the DOM directly.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I don't get your point. Why more succinct ?

Comment: @Alexander I didn't say we shouldn't use a loop, I wanted to point out that this loop is really not effective because it query the DOM twice on each iteration which is really bad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I'm not really sure what the issue is in the above code, but I was able to work around it with:

```
while (table.find(".functionCodeLine").size() < lineNumber) {

    console.log(table.(".functionCodeLine").size());

    funcLineRow = $('<tr class="functionCodeLine"></tr>');
    table.append(funcLineRow);

...
}
```

Comment: If it works, could you mark the question as resolved please ?

Answer (score 0):

try this statement

```
$(".functionCodeLine").length
```

Comment: While it's better practice to use `length`, this won't fix the OPs problem as `size()` and `length` return equivalent values.

Comment: Yes, length produces the same result.

Comment: It is still better to use .length however, even if not the solution: "The .size() method is functionally equivalent to the .length property; however, the .length property is preferred because it does not have the overhead of a function call."